# Default thumb - how to set it

Tags: post-thumbnails

i need the code which will add default thumb, if there is not featured image available. I was using default thumb plus for this but this plugin is using a lot of resource so i need to remove it.

I was trying to follow this [tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-set-a-default-fallback-image-for-wordpress-post-thumbnails/)

But no luck. Inside my widget i have this code

```
<?php if (  (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())  ) { ?>
```

Edited : And whole code  you can see here pastebin.com/715evL1E

Any idea how to this ? thanks

I tried also with suggested code but i got an error .This is what i try the last in index.php

```
<?php if (  (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())  ) { ?>


                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('large-thumb'); } ?>
  <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/transfer-deadline-150x150.jpg" /><?php } ?></a>
```

Comment: Is this being added inside the loop?  And what is the URL to your fallback thumb image?

Answer (score 1):

While there's no such functionality built into core, there's a [***Track Ticket***](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18951) I proposed 2 years ago. You can simply rip of the functionality from the suggested [`wp_default_img()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/18951/18951.patch) function. I'll greatly appreciate any support in comments on that ticket, as this would be highly needed for every theme developer. Thanks in advance.

### MU-Plugin

The following code is meant to be dropped into your `~/wp-content/mu-plugins` folder (or whatever you named it). It will then per default be available in every site on a network install or simply everywhere in your single site install. Use it like this:

```
default_img( array( /* attributes - see doc block */ ) );
```

Just save the code below into a new file with any name and you're ready to go.

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;
/**
 * Plugin Name: Default Image template tag
 * Plugin URI: http://unserkaiser.com
 * Description: Adds a default image template tag
 * Version: 0.1
 * Author: Franz Josef Kaiser
 * Author URI: http://unserkaiser.com
 * License: GNU GPL 2 <https://gist.github.com/1365159>
 */

/**
 * Default image
 *
 * Builds an default <img> for use in themes or plugins before any other images are added.
 * Resizes & crops the image using the built-in (retireved via `get_intermediate_image_sizes();`)
 * or custom image (added via `add_image_size();`) sizes.
 *
 * Retrieves calculated resize dimension @uses image_resize_dimensions();
 * Builds the width and height string @uses image_hwstring();
 *
 * @param $attr
 * @internal param $args (array)
 *        string $url URl to the given default image.
 *        string $size Optional. Default is 'medium'.
 *        string (optional) $alt Image Description for the alt attribute.
 *        string (optional) $title Image Description for the title attribute.
 *        string (optional) $align Part of the class name for aligning the image.
 *        string (optional) $echo Wheter to return or echo the $image
 * @return string HTML IMG element for given image attachment
 */
function default_img( $attr )
{
    // Sizes registered via add_image_size();
    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

    $defaults = array(
        'size'    => 'medium',
        'classes' => false,
        'alt'     => '',
        'title'   => '',
        'align'   => 'none',
        'echo'     => true,
    );

    $attr = wp_parse_args( $attr, $defaults );
    $attr = array_map( 'esc_attr', $attr );

    if ( 'thumb' === $attr['size'] )
        $attr['size'] = 'thumbnail';

    // Size in built in sizes - call size setting from DB
    # behavoir in here dependent on @link http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18947
    # if in core, we change to:
    # $sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
    # $size_data = $sizes[ $size ];
    if ( ! in_array(
        $attr['size'],
        array_keys( $_wp_additional_image_sizes )
        ) )
    {
        # @TODO delete?
        $sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();

        // Get option - gladly autoloaded/can use wp_cache_get();
        $size_data['width']  = intval( get_option( "{$attr['size']}_size_w" ) );
        $size_data['height'] = intval( get_option( "{$attr['size']}_size_h" ) );
        // Not sure how this will behave if cropped is false (autoloaded option not added)
        if ( ! $size_data['crop'] = get_option( "{$attr['size']}_crop" ) )
            $attr['crop'] = false;
    }
    // Size array from global registered additional/custom sizes array
    else
    {
        $size_data = $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $attr['size'] ];
    }

    // Retrieve image width & height
    $img_info  = @getimagesize( $attr['url'] );

    // Calculate final dimensions - if "crop" was set to true during add_image_size(), the img will get ... cropped
    $end_sizes = image_resize_dimensions(
        $img_info[0],
        $img_info[1],
        $size_data['width'],
        $size_data['height'],
        $size_data['crop']
    );

    // defaults to px units.
    // Can't get changed, as applying units is not possible
    $hwstring  = trim( image_hwstring(
        $end_sizes[4],
        $end_sizes[5]
    ) );

    // Attributes:
    // Not made required as users tend to do funky things (...and lock screen readers out)
    ! empty( $attr['alt'] ) AND $attr['alt'] = " alt='{$attr['alt']}'";

    if ( ! $attr['title'] )
    {
        $mime = explode( "/", $img_info['mime'] );
        $attr['title'] = sprintf( __( 'default image of type: %1$s' ), ucfirst( $mime[1] ) );
    }

    $attr['title'] = " title='{$attr['title']}'";

    $attr['align'] = " align{$attr['align']}";
    $attr['size']  = " size-{$attr['size']}";

    // Allow filtering of the default attributes
    $attr = apply_filters( 'wp_default_img_attr', $attr );

    // Build class attribute, considering that maybe some attribute was unset via the filter
    $classes  = "class='wp-img-default{$attr['align']}{$attr['classes']}{$attr['size']}'";

    $url   = trim( $attr['url'] );
    $image = "<img src='{$url}' {$hwstring} {$classes}{$attr['alt']}{$attr['title']} />";

    // Allow filtering of output
    $image = apply_filters( 'wp_default_img', $image );

    $attr['echo'] AND print $image;

    return $image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality in WordPress core. You'll have to create, upload, and call your own default Thumbnail if no featured image is selected. For example, if you have a default Thumbnail inside your Theme file structure you can use [has_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail) to check if the current post has a thumbnail and [the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) to display it; both functions have to be used inside [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

```
   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
      the_post_thumbnail();
   } else {
   ?>
      <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/default-thumb.jpg" />
   <?php
   }
?>
```

There are lots of methods to implement; this is just a quick-and-dirty example.

Comment: Hi All, i m not sure where to respond, so i will to this one. This is the code which i trid to add ,but nothing.Also i tried to mix it a little, but errors keep showing. As for the uploaded image of course i add it after ?>/ and i tried here several solutions as my images are inside wp-content/uploads/date/name.jpg  ..so maybe its the best to give the code so you can see it better http://pastebin.com/715evL1E  Thanks all for your help @ChipBennett

Comment: @Max Please, just add the code as edit to your question. Don't hide progress in comments.

Comment: @kaiser , sorry,didnt know that, but i edited now

Answer (score 0):

has_post_thumbnail() function **used without the ID** has to be inside [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

```
while(has_post()) {
  the_post();
  if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
     the_post_thumbnail();
  } else {
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/default-thumb.jpg" />
  <?php
  }
}
```

You can also use has_post_thumbnail() with specific post id:

```
 <?php
     //Just an exampl
     $post_id = 45;
     if ( has_post_thumbnail($post_id) ) {
        //in this case we can not use the_post_thumbnail
         get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail');
     } else {
     ?>
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/default-thumb.jpg" />
     <?php
     }
```

Also, be sure the theme suppports post thumbnails adding this in functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

If you post the full code of your widget I can teach you exactly how to implement the default thumbnail feature.

Comment: This is not an answer, this is just an addendum to Chip Bennett's answer.

Comment: @vancoder What's wrong with that? Yes, it could as well have been an edit, but people reading it will still honor this question as well if they found Chips answer useful.

Comment: "If you wish to improve an existing answer, click the edit link beneath it." http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: I've edited now the Chip Bennett's answer, but honestly I think the original answer was really very incomplete and could be in the no-answer zone. I will delete this answer if the edition is accepted.

Comment: @cybnet Approved edit.

Comment: Just for clarification: I kept part of the edit, but removed the bulk. The nature of the question isn't how to implement post thumbnails, but rather ''how to define a default fallback'' if no featured image is defined for a given post. So, while everything in your answer is valuable and useful information, it doesn't help answer the question at hand.

Comment: Still, no answer or solution which worked..and I am still in a need of help with this..thanks

Comment: Actually you have three answers of how to do it. If you still can not implment a default thumb, you are near to fall in the "do the job for me" side. Anyway, if you want more help you sould answer the questions you have been asked about how you are using the suggested code; the full code you are trying can be also helpful as we will can see the possible error(s) of your implementation of the code.

Comment: Well, i tried every mix i could think of.And i did answer to question, i even added the code and added one of things which i tried..so i m not sure where is the problem. What ever i do , i receive an error message. I tried also to add Mu plugin folder and this file inside of it, added a proper link, no errors but nothing happens.As i said i am newbie and i dont know what i m doing wrong, but i tried everything.